# Removing html tags but keep breaklines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

We need to make up a text with html markup and without (for mails)
So i have ckeditor to makeup the text with html markup, but when i delete the markup with a script al breaklines are gone, because the script strips the `<p>` tags. and i'm left with one long string of text instead of a descent layout.
Anyone an idea how i can keep the breaklines?

```
function strip(){
        var html = CKEDITOR.instances.Maintext.getData();
        var text = $(html).text(); 
        document.getElementById('nohtmltext').value = text;
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/pre

Comment: Those are paragraphs, not "breaklines" which would be `<br />` in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution with some help from the answers given.

```
function strip(){
            var html = CKEDITOR.instances.Maintext.getData();
            html = html.replace(/<p>/g,'');
            html = html.replace(/<\/p>/g,'\n\n');
            var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
            tempDiv.innerHTML = html;
            var text = $(tempDiv).text(); 
            document.getElementById('nohtmltext').value = text;
        }
```

I know this is not the most beautiful bit of code i'v ever written, but it does exactly what i want.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this is to replace all your "p-tags" with "\n".

```
html.replace('<p>','').replace('</p>','\n\n').text(); // not tested
```

Comment: This helped me good, but now i can't remove the other html tags wit .text() anymore
function strip(){
            var html = CKEDITOR.instances.Maintext.getData();
            html = html.replace(/<p>/g,'');
            html = html.replace(/<\/p>/g,'\n\n');
            var text = $(html).text(); 
            document.getElementById('nohtmltext').value = text;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Wrong:

```
function strip(){
        var html = CKEDITOR.instances.Maintext.getData();
        var text = $(html).text(); 
        document.getElementById('nohtmltext').value = text;
}
```

Good:

```
function strip(){
    var html = CKEDITOR.instances.Maintext.getData();
    document.getElementById('nohtmltext').innerHTML = html;
}
```

Comment: "because the script strips the <p> tags. and i'm left with one long string of text instead of a descent layout" - so what's your intention? Do you want to remove everything but `<p>`s?